# Check box style issue in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have fixed **checkbox** width and height with CSS, its work fine in IE browser but not in Mozila Firefox

Please visit this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/avcreative/uYVVr/3/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this css:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width:9px;
    height:9px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```